# How to use different color for topojson objects with openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, topojson

I have topojson with a bundle of objects, like **level1**, **level2**, **level3**:

```js
{
    "type": "Topology",
    "transform": …,
    "objects": {
        "level1": {
            "id":"level1",
            "type":"GeometryCollection",
            "geometries":[
                {"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]]}
            ]
         },
        "level2": …,
        "level3": …,
    },
    "arcs": …
}
```

and I would like to define different color for different object. I'm using it in openlayers 3 as a vector layer:

```js
new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.TopoJSON({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        url: "url to my topojson"
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        return new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#09a7ee',
                width: 1
            })
        });
    }
})
```

My idea is to get the object (level1) id and select color by it or something like that. But I don't know how to get the property id in style function.

```js
...
style: function(feature) {
    var id = feature.get('id'); //This is not working
    var colors = {
        'level1': '#09a7ee',
        'level2': '#aaa7ee',
        ...
    }

    return new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: colors[id],
            width: 1
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ol.format.TopoJSON` does not store the group keys, so you'll have to build an index from the TopoJSON:

```js
var geometries, geometry;
for (var key in response.objects) {
    geometries = response.objects[key].geometries || [];
    for (var i = 0, ii = geometries.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        geometry = geometries[i];
        objectsByKey[geometry.id] = key;
    }
}
var features = new ol.format.TopoJSON()
    .readFeatures(response, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
```

The above assumes that `response` is the JSON object containing your TopoJSON, and that you're going to construct a vector source with `features`.

Once you have this, you can do something like this in your `styleFunction`:

```js
...
style: (function(feature) {
    var colors = {
        'level1': '#09a7ee',
        'level2': '#aaa7ee',
        ...
    };
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 1
      })
    });
    var styles = [style];

    return function(feature) {
      var group = objectsByKey[feature.getId()];
      style.getStroke().setColor(colors[group]);
      return styles;
    });
})()
```